# Convert a combination of string and list to a csv file

Tags: linux, csv, unix, awk, formatting

I have a comma separated file which has a combination of strings and list and *It looks like this*

```
24.33,-30.59,42542,['2.4', '3.6', '4.4', '5.8', '6.6', '7.2','9.4', '9.4', '9.8']
24.33,-30.60,25512,['1.4', '2.6', '2.8', '3.8', '4.6', '5.2','7.4', '8', '9']
```

*I want something like this*

```
24.33,-30.59,42542,2.4,3.6,4.4,5.8,6.6,7.2,9.4,9.4,9.8
24.33,-30.60,25512,1.4,2.6,2.8,3.8,4.6,5.2,7.4,8,9
```

What can be the best and easiest way to do this

Comment: please add what you have tried.. from given sample, looks like you can simply delete all spaces, quotes and square brackets.. `tr` would be a good tool for that task..

Comment: Hi, you can try with `awk` : `awk -F '[,[]+' -v OFS=',' -v RS=']\n' '{$1=$1;} 1'`

Comment: @Gioconda all else aside (e.g. `[,[]` will not work - you mean `[],]`), that would require GNU awk for multi-char RS so you should state that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple substitutions on individual lines is the job sed exists to do:

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9,.-]//g' file
24.33,-30.59,42542,2.4,3.6,4.4,5.8,6.6,7.2,9.4,9.4,9.8
24.33,-30.60,25512,1.4,2.6,2.8,3.8,4.6,5.2,7.4,8,9
```

but you could use tr for this too:

```
$ tr -cd '0-9,.\n-' < file
24.33,-30.59,42542,2.4,3.6,4.4,5.8,6.6,7.2,9.4,9.4,9.8
24.33,-30.60,25512,1.4,2.6,2.8,3.8,4.6,5.2,7.4,8,9
```

and if you insist on awk it'd be:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[^0-9,.-]/,"")}1' file
24.33,-30.59,42542,2.4,3.6,4.4,5.8,6.6,7.2,9.4,9.4,9.8
24.33,-30.60,25512,1.4,2.6,2.8,3.8,4.6,5.2,7.4,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/\[|\]/,"");gsub(/\047/,"");gsub(/, /,",")} 1'  Input_file
```

OR more precisely(reducing one more `gsub` from above code):

```
awk '{gsub(/\[|\]|\047/,"");gsub(/, /,",")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/\[|\]|\047/,"") ##globally substituting [, ] and single dash with NULL in current line.
  gsub(/, /,",")        ##globally substituting comma with space with only comma in current line.  
}
1                       ##Mentioning 1 here to print the current line
'  Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```